# Torque experienced by a current carrying circular coil

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that the torque experience by a current carrying loop in a uniform magnetic field is given by *Torque* $= MB$ where $M$ is the magnetic moment of the loop. In my book, the derivation was provided only for a rectangular loop and was given that it can be extended to other loops as well.

But intuitively when I try to apply this derivation for a circular coil, I get net torque is equal to $0$. Can somebody help me prove that torque experienced by a current carrying coil in uniform magnetic field is equal to $MB$.

I am currently in high school.

Comment: Would you like to share your work so that we get where you got wrong

Comment: The torque isn’t simply $MB$. It depends on how the loop is oriented in the field. The torque is the vector product $\vec{M}\times\vec{B}$.

Comment: -@Niescte, I've answered a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/573466/integration-of-torque-for-a-circular-current-loop-in-magnetic-field/573633#573633) for circular coil.

Comment: What i did was assume that the magnetic field makes and angle theta with the plane of the coil and then observe it from a side so that it looks like a rod.Since the ends have length nearly equal to zero, i got net torque to be equal to 0 exactly like the derivation for a rectangular loop.